# Regression Analysis in agriculture

Tags: regression, modeling

I am from the field of Agriculture and here in Agriculture I will say there is a gap of practicing some advanced statistical analystic system, I am not sure about other university but at list in my University.

When I come to my question, I did some experimenent let us say I have around 10 different soils they have around 5 properties (propery 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5) and I have added some additive in four different ratio (control, ratio 1, 2, 3 and 4) to each soils. And I confirmed that my additive significantly affected my soils Nitrogen content. (it is just for example)

- some more explanations about my expt.
  I have 10 soils. I put from each soils in same sized 15 pots ( so i have 150 pots = 15 * 10) and from this 15 pots 3 are control (no fertilizer), 3 have 1 % fertilize, 3 have 2 % fertilizer, 3 have 4 % fertilize and the remaining 3 have 8 % fertilizer. each ten soils have their unique properties like Nitrogen content pH or CEC. And I want to now how this three initial unique properties of my soils (Nitrogen, pH and CEC) affected the ability of my fertilizer to increase soil Calcium content.

I thank you for your explanations. If the question is not much clear i will try to explain it more as needed. Looking forward.

Comment: It's worth noting that R.A. Fisher developed and extended ANOVA using plots of soil from agricultural experiments. Moreover and as Cohen noted in his papers and books on regression as a general data analytic system, ANOVA is a subset of regression. So, read up on ANOVA.

Comment: Maybe response surface methodology could help (c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Response_surface_methodology)

Comment: Maybe you could give some details of your actual experiment, what is purpose, details of designs, number of experimental plots, ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen. My experimental design is completely randomized experimental design where I have 10 soil groups and each receiving 4 level of treatment. By using ANOVA I new that my treatment induced significant difference. But what I want to now is how the initial status of the soil affected the capacity of my treatment (property 1, 2, 3, and 4)?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen. I have 10 soils. I put from each soils in same sized 15 pots ( so i have 150 pots = 15 * 10) and from this 15 pots 3 are control (no fertilizer), 3 have 1 % fertilize, 3 have 2 % fertilizer, 3 have 4 % fertilize and the remaining 3 have 8 % fertilizer. each ten soils have their unique properties like Nitrogen content pH or CEC. And I want to now how this three initial unique properties of my soils (Nitrogen, pH and CEC) affected the ability of my fertilizer to increase soil Calcium content.

Comment: Can you please add this new information to the original question? Few people read the comments ...

Answer (score 0):

fellow ag. student

I would do an ANOVA on your results to see if Ca (∆Ca= Ca treatment-Ca control) differed as a function of N, pH, and CEC content. If you do not want to include the effect of soil type you should think about writing a mixed effects model with soil type as your random variable. If there was a difference in 
∆Ca content, then you could simply report mean ∆Ca values.